# How to Delegate a user to read friend's data on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new FB programming. 
When an application  get some user's token, this app can only get data from his profile(like,, pages,groups, comments, shares etc..), and cannot read this kind of data from his friends (it can  only  get friends name list). 
Does anybody know if it's possible (by code) to delegate some user to read his friends data and send it back to the application ?

Comment: What data are you looking to use? You might want to give [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/) a look

Comment: Are you telling me that I can access friends data with that object?

Comment: Please could you specify what data of friends do you require? I just gave you hint about the permissions required to get data from friends.

Comment: ok. i'd like to access friend's data(likes, own pages, groups,personal info(age, location, ect), comments, shares)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access these data of a User's friend after you have obtained corresponding [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/). After you have obtained these, you just need to query the User's friend with his User ID similar to your User and you will retrieve the required data.

As you are interested in likes, own pages, groups, presonal information and status update you will require `friends_likes`, `friends_groups`, `friends_location`, `friends_birthday` and `friends_status`. You can not know the Pages the friend of your User is administrating. Accessing the data is same as how you would get data for User, like to get the groups your friend is member of you would query

```
/friends_id/groups
```

To get an idea about about connections User have and what you should use, check [User's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Question:  You said I cannot know  the pages that friends of your Users is administrating...But is there a way to query public pages using JOIN with friends ID to retrieve page's adimin? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#admins    Are facebook pages public ?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way. You can query admins of a Page only by Page Access Token, which is retrieved through one of the admin giving `manage_pages` permission, which I think you might not get for all the Pages on the Facebook.